# fastest way to multiprocess several 10K lines file read in python3

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to multiprocessing the reading of several (350 in this case) GZ files of 10K lines each in a python3 script in order to further compare them with other files.

I retrieve the list of file from another "index" file:

```
###read index file
with open( index_file, "r" ) as fi :
    i_linee = fi.read().splitlines()

files_list = [ os.path.join( dirname, l.split(",")[0]) for l in i_linee ]
```

I previously created a function to read the file and return the result:

```
def readlines_file(single_file) :
with gzip.open( single_file, 'rb' ) as pf :
    linee = pf.read().decode("utf-8").splitlines()
    linee = [ ll.split("\t") for ll in linee ]
return linee
```

and then I try to pass it to a multiprocess, I need to merge all the lines in a single object, I red that I should use Pool for such kind of work:

```
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3) as pool:
    results = pool.map_async(readlines_file, files_list)
```

**MULTIPROCESS WHOLE execution time 5.6654 seconds**

if I compare it to same function without using multiprocessing it appears to be slower!

```
###NOT MULTIPROCESSING:
pz_lines = []
for f in files_list :
    pz_lines.extend(readlines_file(f))
```

**WHOLE execution time 3.9624 seconds**

so I am wondering if I am getting something wrong or if you suggest that this is effectively the fastest way to do it? Would map or something else fit better? 
PS how can I then retrieve the lines from the results to merge them?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Comment: Sadly you can't really take advantage of multiprocessing here as what probably slows you down are the disk access. There is an overhead to multiprocessing, that's the reason why the second is faster.

Comment: would you suggest to merge all subfiles in one big file and then make a sort of multiprocess chunk read over it?

Comment: No, I suggest that the fastest way to read all your files is probably to read them using a sequential code as reading the disk will be sequential anyway. On the other hand, while your file is loaded in memory you can probably optimize the computation you do on them later. I may be missing something, but I really think that this execution time you have here (~4s) can't really be reduced.